# How to create a column that contains the penultimate value of each row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame and I need to create a new column  which contains the second largest value of each row in the original Dataframe.

**Sample:**

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, 80).reshape(8, -1))
```

**Desired output:**

```
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  penultimate
0  52  69  62   7  20  69  38  10  57  17           62
1  52  94  49  63   1  90  14  76  20  84           90
2  78  37  58   7  27  41  27  26  48  51           58
3   6  39  99  36  62  90  47  25  60  84           90
4  37  36  91  93  76  69  86  95  69   6           93
5   5  54  73  61  22  29  99  27  46  24           73
6  71  65  45   9  63  46   4  93  36  18           71
7  85   7  76  46  65  97  64  52  28  80           85
```

How can this be done in as little code as possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple lambda function!

```
# Input
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, 80).reshape(8, -1))

# Output
out = df.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values().unique()[-2], axis=1)
df['penultimate'] = out
print(df)
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You could use `NumPy` for this:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,100, 80).reshape(8, -1))
df['penultimate'] = np.sort(df.values, 1)[:, -2]
print(df)
```

Using `NumPy` is faster.